# For interactions, how do I find when values of the DV are significantly different from one another?

Tags: regression, interaction

Ran a continuous interaction that was significant. I centered the IVs and plotted the interaction with 2 regression lines(-1SD and +1SD of the moderator). A reviewer asked me to update my interaction figure to indicate when values of the DV become significantly different from one another. While I know the interaction was significant, I have no idea how to test at what level of the IV the levels of the DV become significantly different at -1SD and +1SD of the moderator. Any advice would be much appreciated - thanks in advance!